# Constant script -> change src iframe (1min, 5min) + jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, iframe, settimeout

I'm having problems writing a script in jQuery.

I have an `iFrame` in my page that needs to change. 
The source of the iframe has to be `http://www.example1.com` for **ONE minute** and then switched to `http://www.example2.com` for **FIVE minutes**. This in a **constant loop**. But how can I do this?

I now have:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    setTimeout(function() {
        if($('#iframe').attr('src') == "http://www.example1.com")
        {
            $('#iframe').attr('src',"http://www.example2.com");
        }
        else
        {
            $('#iframe').attr('src',"http://www.example1.com");
        }
    }, 10000);
});
```

But this doesn't do so much. And it only runs once ..

Comment: Better to replace the iframe element with a new one than modify the src attribute.  Modifying the src attribute will make an entry in the browser history.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe this will work. Each time one of the functions is called, it sets a new timeout for the other function. You initally show 1, then set a 1 minute timeout. When that timeout expires, 2 is shown and a new timeout is set for 5 minutes, at which point, 1 will be shown again.

```
function show1() { 
    iframe.attr('src', 'http://www.example1.com');
    setTimeout(function() { show2(); }, 1000 * 60);
}
function show2() { 
    iframe.attr('src', 'http://www.example2.com');
    setTimeout(function() { show1(); }, 1000 * 60 * 5);
}

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    show1();
});
```

Comment: @nielsv there is no need in global functions, it is better is this case to use functions within the closure.

Comment: @Cheery Good point - I'd still stick with named functions just so it's easier to see what you're doing, but keeping them local inside the jQuery function would help keep the global namespace clean.

Answer (score 0):

Set initial `src` of iframe as `http://www.example1.com` and ...

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
   var runme = function() {
      var iframe = $('#iframe');

      setTimeout(function() { // first callback
         iframe.attr('src', 'http://www.example2.com');
      }, 1000 * 60);          // change to example2 after 1 minute

      setTimeout(function() { // second callback
         iframe.attr('src', 'http://www.example1.com');
         runme();             // loop
      }, (1000 + 5000) * 60); // change to example1 after 6 minutes (1 + 5)
   };

   runme();
});
```

This code prepares two timeouts, with one callback function executed after 1 minute and second callback executed after 1 + 5 = 6 minutes. Second callback 'rearms' these two timeouts and so on..

If you do not want to setup initial `src`, the code can be written as

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
   var runme = function() {
      var iframe = $('#iframe');

      iframe.attr('src', 'http://www.example1.com');  // set to example1

      setTimeout(function() {
         iframe.attr('src', 'http://www.example2.com');
         setTimeout(runme, 5000 * 60); // repeat after 5 minutes 
      }, 1000 * 60);          // change to example2 after 1 minute
   };

   runme();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
(function () {
    var iframe = document.getElementById('iframe')
        , urlA = 'http://www.example1.com'
        , urlB = 'http://www.example2.com'
        , delayA = 60000
        , delayB = 300000
        , delay = iframe.getAttribute('src') === urlA ? delayA : delayB
        , timeoutCallback = function () {
            iframe.setAttribute('src', iframe.getAttribute('src') === urlA ? urlB : urlA);
            delay = delay === delayA ? delayB : delayA;

            // Set new timeout with updated delay
            setTimeout(timeoutCallback, delay)
        };

    // Start.
    setTimeout(timeoutCallback, delay);
}());
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also create one interval callback that checks every 100ms if it's time to show the next content. Maybe it's a bit more complicated than the other approaches.

But if you include this as an external script it's only 3 lines of code to load what you want.

As alternative to an iframe you could also load the external file into an object tag. I have used it in the demo below. You can also find the same code as jsFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/fss7Leza/).

If you prefer the iframe I have added the code for it in the loadData function as comment.

(I've set the time in the demo to 1 minute for each content but this can be changed as you like.)

```js
var timedLoader = (function ($) {
    
    var tick = 100; // 100ms
    
    var that;
    function Scheduler() {
        this.schedule = [];
        this.lastTick = (new Date()).getTime();
        this.currentTask = 0;
        this.currentDuration = 0;
        this.elapsed = 0;
        
        that = this;
        this.startTaskRunner();
    }
    
    Scheduler.prototype.startTaskRunner = function() {
        setInterval(this.taskRunner, tick);
    };
    
    Scheduler.prototype.taskRunner = function() {
        // elapsed time
        var now = (new Date()).getTime();
        that.elapsed = now - that.lastTick;
        
        var sched = that.schedule; // reference to schedule to shorten the code
        
        if ( sched.length > 0 ) {
            // at least one task available
            if ( that.currentDuration == 0 ) {
                that.currentDuration = sched[that.currentTask].displayTime * 60 * 1000; // scale to milli seconds
                console.log('start duration = ' + that.currentDuration);
                console.log('task = ' + that.currentTask);
                
                loadData(sched[that.currentTask].url);
            }
            else
            {
                that.currentDuration -= that.elapsed;
                //console.log(that.currentDuration);   
                if (that.currentDuration <= 0) {
                    // total time elapsed
                    that.currentDuration = 0;
                    that.currentTask++;
                    
                    // check if rollover required
                    if (that.currentTask > sched.length-1) that.currentTask = 0;
                }
            }
        }
        
        that.lastTick = now; // copy new to old
    };
    
    // time in minutes
    Scheduler.prototype.addTask = function(url, time) {
        this.schedule.push({'url': url, 'displayTime': time});
    };
    
    var loadData = function (src) {
        $('#container').html('<object type="text/html" data="'+ src +'"></object>');
        //$('#container').html('<iframe src="'+ src +'"></iframe>');
    };
    
    return {
        loadData: loadData,
        Scheduler: Scheduler
    };
})(jQuery);

$(function () {
    //timedLoader.loadData('http://www.example.com/');
    
    var loader = new timedLoader.Scheduler(); // start and init scheduler
    loader.addTask('http://www.example.com/', 1); // url to load, time in minutes
    loader.addTask('http://www.example1.com/', 1);
    //loader.addTask('http://www.wikipedia.org/', 1);
});
```

```css
object, iframe {
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>

<!-- <object type="text/html" data="http://www.example.com/" ></object>-->
```